# Adding a new choice in a complexType with choices from a second XSD importing/including the main XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have one XSD in which i have a complexType is defined with some choices, for example...

```
<xs:complexType name="ABC">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="a" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="b" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:choice>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now if I want to add more choices to the existing sequence for the complexType ABC, but through another XSD file as I do not want to alter the first one for custom changes. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: you can use xs:redefine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <xs:include schemaLocation="abc.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="abcde">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ABC">
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element name="c"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```